# mysql generic syntax error for declaration of variable from LAST_INSERT_ID() - hard to analyse

Tags: mysql, mysql-variables

I am attempting to set a variable based on the insert id of a an insert. So I wrote:

```
INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name, middle_names, suffix, title)
VALUES ("Frank", "Thring", "", "", "Mr");
SET @person_frank_thring_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO address (line2, line3, postcode, state, suburb)
VALUES ("Dock 3", "22 Boundary Rd", 2088, "NSW", "Mascot");
SET @address_franks_aircraft_maintenance_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO contact (email, phone)
VALUES ("info@franks.com", "0245732552");
SET @contact_franks_aircraft_maintenance_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO maintainer (abn, address_id, contact_id, nk, name, person_id)
VALUES (73507986550, @address_franks_aircraft_maintenance_id, @contact_franks_aircraft_maintenance_id,
"c49439a4-a24a-4e1b-bc92-ebad6caf5e74", "Frank's Airplane Repairs", @person_frank_thring_id);
SET @maintainer_franks_maint_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO approved_process (nk, approval_number, description, expires, maintainer_id)
VALUES ("ee114aab-d201-498d-85a4-2b95e9df8b3d", "13226A", "Welding and Heat Treatment", "2021-05-02", @maintainer_franks_maint_id);
```

person, address, contact and maintainer are all pre-existing tables. And I ran the first three inserts in isolation, and I checked that the data were inserted into the tables. When I run the whole block I get a very generic error:

> [ERROR in query 73] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@maintainer_franks_maint_id' at line 2
>   Execution stopped!

EDIT - Please see the DROP and CREATE statements below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS address;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contact;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS maintainer;

CREATE TABLE person (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    middle_names varchar(255),
    suffix varchar(255),
    title varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

CREATE TABLE address (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    line1 varchar(255),
    line2 varchar(255),
    line3 varchar(255),
    postcode integer,
    state varchar(255),
    suburb varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

CREATE TABLE contact (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email varchar(255),
    fax varchar(255),
    mobile varchar(255),
    phone varchar(255),
    address_id bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

CREATE TABLE maintainer (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    abn bigint,
    image varchar(255),
    nk varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    address_id bigint,
    contact_id bigint,
    person_id bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

ALTER TABLE maintainer 
ADD CONSTRAINT UK_maintainer_nk unique (nk);

ALTER TABLE maintainer 
ADD CONSTRAINT FKs7jo395jusgm3631g7w845wy4 FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address (id);

ALTER TABLE maintainer 
ADD CONSTRAINT FKgixmfq21peg70qtff3q4ktq1 FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES contact (id);

ALTER TABLE maintainer 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK86boj3163qysduc7x3a2m84mh FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person (id);
```

and adding approved+process:

```
CREATE TABLE approved_process (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nk varchar(255),
    approval_number varchar(255),
    description varchar(255),
    expires date,
    maintainer_id bigint,
    subcontractor_id bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: What are you running these queries through? And you say the first four are "pre-existing tables"; what does that make the fourth? Just something newly created, or is there something else different about it? What does the CREATE TABLE for it look like?

Comment: well, I was using sequel pro, although the same thing happens on the mysql command line, so I don't think its the software. The overall script is quite large, so I felt it was not a good idea to present it all here, but I have updated the answer with the relevant creates.

Comment: There is no definition for `approved_process`?

Comment: yes, sorry, there is, i'll add it now

Comment: I would check if the space before `@maintainer_franks_maint_id` is a proper space, or some kind of a special character.

Comment: Yea, I thought of that too, so I checked the space before, the spaces between the '=' sign the variable string itself, the apostrophe in the name frank's and a few other spaces in the insert. So far all seem to check out. I actually shortened the variable name before this post, just in case there was some limitation in that as well.

Comment: There must be something being lost in the copy paste from your source to here, because that all runs fine in sql fiddle. [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5479e/1)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, it appears to be user error at some level. There were two problems: One was a strange invisible character at the beginning of the `INSERT INTO approved_process` line and also, for some reason Sequel Pro couldn't tell the difference between `@franks` in the email value and @franks at the beginning of the variable declaration.